# Call a function within different iframes with jQuery

Tags: jquery

In a single page I load two external contents into two div (ie. #div1, #div2).The content is located in the same serve. To do this I use this I use this script:

```
function sack(file) {
    this.xmlhttp = null;

    this.resetData = function() {
        this.method = "POST";
        this.queryStringSeparator = "?";
        this.argumentSeparator = "&";
        this.URLString = "";
        this.encodeURIString = true;
        this.execute = false;
        this.element = null;
        this.elementObj = null;
        this.requestFile = file;
        this.vars = new Object();
        this.responseStatus = new Array(2);
    };

    this.resetFunctions = function() {
        this.onLoading = function() { };
        this.onLoaded = function() { };
        this.onInteractive = function() { };
        this.onCompletion = function() { };
        this.onError = function() { };
        this.onFail = function() { };
    };

    this.reset = function() {
        this.resetFunctions();
        this.resetData();
    };

    this.createAJAX = function() {
        try {
            this.xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e1) {
            try {
                this.xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e2) {
                this.xmlhttp = null;
            }
        }

        if (! this.xmlhttp) {
            if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
                this.xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                this.failed = true;
            }
        }
    };

    this.setVar = function(name, value){
        this.vars[name] = Array(value, false);
    };

    this.encVar = function(name, value, returnvars) {
        if (true == returnvars) {
            return Array(encodeURIComponent(name), encodeURIComponent(value));
        } else {
            this.vars[encodeURIComponent(name)] = Array(encodeURIComponent(value), true);
        }
    }

    this.processURLString = function(string, encode) {
        encoded = encodeURIComponent(this.argumentSeparator);
        regexp = new RegExp(this.argumentSeparator + "|" + encoded);
        varArray = string.split(regexp);
        for (i = 0; i < varArray.length; i++){
            urlVars = varArray[i].split("=");
            if (true == encode){
                this.encVar(urlVars[0], urlVars[1]);
            } else {
                this.setVar(urlVars[0], urlVars[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    this.createURLString = function(urlstring) {
        if (this.encodeURIString && this.URLString.length) {
            this.processURLString(this.URLString, true);
        }

        if (urlstring) {
            if (this.URLString.length) {
                this.URLString += this.argumentSeparator + urlstring;
            } else {
                this.URLString = urlstring;
            }
        }

        // prevents caching of URLString
        this.setVar("rndval", new Date().getTime());

        urlstringtemp = new Array();
        for (key in this.vars) {
            if (false == this.vars[key][1] && true == this.encodeURIString) {
                encoded = this.encVar(key, this.vars[key][0], true);
                delete this.vars[key];
                this.vars[encoded[0]] = Array(encoded[1], true);
                key = encoded[0];
            }

            urlstringtemp[urlstringtemp.length] = key + "=" + this.vars[key][0];
        }
        if (urlstring){
            this.URLString += this.argumentSeparator + urlstringtemp.join(this.argumentSeparator);
        } else {
            this.URLString += urlstringtemp.join(this.argumentSeparator);
        }
    }

    this.runResponse = function() {
        eval(this.response);
    }

    this.runAJAX = function(urlstring) {
        if (this.failed) {
            this.onFail();
        } else {
            this.createURLString(urlstring);
            if (this.element) {
                this.elementObj = document.getElementById(this.element);
            }
            if (this.xmlhttp) {
                var self = this;
                if (this.method == "GET") {
                    totalurlstring = this.requestFile + this.queryStringSeparator + this.URLString;
                    this.xmlhttp.open(this.method, totalurlstring, true);
                } else {
                    this.xmlhttp.open(this.method, this.requestFile, true);
                    try {
                        this.xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    } catch (e) { }
                }

                this.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    switch (self.xmlhttp.readyState) {
                        case 1:
                            self.onLoading();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            self.onLoaded();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            self.onInteractive();
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            self.response = self.xmlhttp.responseText;
                            self.responseXML = self.xmlhttp.responseXML;
                            self.responseStatus[0] = self.xmlhttp.status;
                            self.responseStatus[1] = self.xmlhttp.statusText;

                            if (self.execute) {
                                self.runResponse();
                            }

                            if (self.elementObj) {
                                elemNodeName = self.elementObj.nodeName;
                                elemNodeName.toLowerCase();
                                if (elemNodeName == "input"
                                || elemNodeName == "select"
                                || elemNodeName == "option"
                                ) {
                                    self.elementObj.value = self.response;
                                } else {
                                    self.elementObj.innerHTML = self.response;
                                }
                            }
                            if (self.responseStatus[0] == "200") {
                                self.onCompletion();
                            } else {
                                self.onError();
                            }

                            self.URLString = "";
                            /* These lines were added by Alf Magne Kalleland ref. info on the sack home page. It prevents memory leakage in IE */

                            delete self.xmlhttp['onreadystatechange'];
                            self.xmlhttp=null;
                            self.responseStatus=null;
                            self.response=null;
                            self.responseXML=null;

                            break;
                    }
                };

                this.xmlhttp.send(this.URLString);
            }
        }
    };

    this.reset();
    this.createAJAX();
}
var enableCache = true;
var jsCache = new Array();

var dynamicContent_ajaxObjects = new Array();

function ajax_showContent(divId,ajaxIndex,url)
{
    var targetObj = document.getElementById(divId);
    targetObj.innerHTML = dynamicContent_ajaxObjects[ajaxIndex].response;
    if(enableCache){
        jsCache[url] =  dynamicContent_ajaxObjects[ajaxIndex].response;
    }
    dynamicContent_ajaxObjects[ajaxIndex] = false;

    ajax_parseJs(targetObj)
}

function ajax_loadContent(divId,url)
{
    if(enableCache && jsCache[url]){
        document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = jsCache[url];
        ajax_parseJs(document.getElementById(divId))
        evaluateCss(document.getElementById(divId))
        return;
    }

    var ajaxIndex = dynamicContent_ajaxObjects.length;
    document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = '<p class="sidebar_element" style="background-color: #ffffff; border:none;" align="center">Operazione in corso...<br /><br/><img src="http://www.wiitalia.it/wp-content/themes/wiitalia/images/loading.gif"><br></p>';
    dynamicContent_ajaxObjects[ajaxIndex] = new sack();

    if(url.indexOf('?')>=0){
        dynamicContent_ajaxObjects[ajaxIndex].method='GET';
        var string = url.substring(url.indexOf('?'));
        url = url.replace(string,'');
        string = string.replace('?','');
        var items = string.split(/&/g);
        for(var no=0;no<items.length;no++){
            var tokens = items[no].split('=');
            if(tokens.length==2){
                dynamicContent_ajaxObjects[ajaxIndex].setVar(tokens[0],tokens[1]);
            }   
        }   
        url = url.replace(string,'');
    }


    dynamicContent_ajaxObjects[ajaxIndex].requestFile = url;    // Specifying which file to get
    dynamicContent_ajaxObjects[ajaxIndex].onCompletion = function(){ ajax_showContent(divId,ajaxIndex,url); };  // Specify function that will be executed after file has been found
    dynamicContent_ajaxObjects[ajaxIndex].runAJAX();        // Execute AJAX function    


}

function ajax_parseJs(obj)
{
    var scriptTags = obj.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT');
    var string = '';
    var jsCode = '';
    for(var no=0;no<scriptTags.length;no++){    
        if(scriptTags[no].src){
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            var scriptObj = document.createElement("script");

            scriptObj.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            scriptObj.setAttribute("src", scriptTags[no].src);      
        }else{
            if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('opera')>=0){
                jsCode = jsCode + scriptTags[no].text + '\n';
            }
            else
                jsCode = jsCode + scriptTags[no].innerHTML; 
        }

    }

    if(jsCode)ajax_installScript(jsCode);
}


function ajax_installScript(script)
{       
    if (!script)
        return;     
    if (window.execScript){         
        window.execScript(script)
    }else if(window.jQuery && jQuery.browser.safari){ // safari detection in jQuery
        window.setTimeout(script,0);
    }else{          
        window.setTimeout( script, 0 );
    } 
}   


function evaluateCss(obj)
{
    var cssTags = obj.getElementsByTagName('STYLE');
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0];
    for(var no=0;no<cssTags.length;no++){
        head.appendChild(cssTags[no]);
    }   
}
```

Is it possible to call in the second div a function that is located in the first div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call functions across two windows, frames and iframes, as long as the two are both on the same domain. The functions need to be in the global scope, which is the same as being properties of the window object

In window 1:

```
function windowOneFunction(){
   //do something
}
```

In window 2

```
windowOne.windowOneFunction()
```

Answer (score 3):

No, this is restriction of [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which won't let you to do such an action.

Comment: And is it possible if instead of iframes I load external content into a div through jquery?

Comment: @Penny you can't load external content into a div, if you mean from another server, until it's JSONP or until server allows your origin

Comment: I already do that, it's dinamic content loaded from the same server

Comment: @Penny that's a lot of code. please add only relative functions/code